# Clicking the 'get project' button on careers 2.0 produces no effect and creates JS error in console

Tags: bug, jobs

The same happens when adding an article, and a book you've read:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <p><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="q" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></p>
```

Comment: That's a nasty error! In what page exactly does this happen?

Comment: Go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/ > login > my profile > add an application... > enter url and click 'get project'

Comment: Yeah it is a duplicate, same problem

Comment: pretty bad bug this, it will actually be stopping people updating their profile and applying for jobs

Comment: I agree it's a bad bug, all bugs are bad and there's nothing further we can do.

Comment: All bugs are bad, some are much worse than others. How can we get the attention of the SO devs?

Comment: Most we can do at the moment is post here. Staff members aka devs roam Meta and take a look from time to time. I do have idea to add "priority" to bug reports, hope to propose it soon but of course can't guarantee anything.